# How to call an application.yaml parameter in the method signature? Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a method whose signature is a String that is placed explicitly, but I would like to add this String message in the application.yaml and call it in the method, as shown below:

```
publishesPublic.replyRefusal(map, "500", "AC0001", "The request could not be processed at this time. Try again later.");
```

How do I leave the message in the application.yaml and call it in the method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it to application.yml with a key :

```yml
error:
   message: The request could not be processed at this time. Try again later.
```

And in you bean, you can inject the value like this :

```java
private String errorMessage;

public YourBean(@Value("${error.message}") String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}
```

You can inject it using field injection too, but using constructor is a better practice.

And then :

```java
publishesPublic.replyRefusal(map, "500", "AC0001", errorMessage);
```

Comment: I tried the way you instructed but you are returning a placeholder error, see my app.yaml:
`Error:
      code: AC0001
      status: 500
      message: The request could not be processed at this time. Try again later.`

See the injection I did:
`@Value("${code}")
    private String code;

    @Value("${status}")
    private String status;

    @Value("${message}")
    private String message;`

Here's what I call the method:
`publishesPublic.replyRefusal(map, code, status, message);`

What can it be?

Comment: @devnan I tried it and it works. Can you show me your application.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Application yaml file will have the following entry.

```
tryAgainMessage: Try again later
```

Get it injected in java code as follows

```
@Value("${tryAgainMessage}")
private String tryAgainMessage;
```

Use it

```
publishesPublic.replyRefusal(map, "500", "AC0001", tryAgainMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work, the placeholder exception is returning, as I mentioned above in response to @FaridMesnata's comment

Comment: From your response in the other comment, did you try @Value("${code}") or @Value("${Error.code}")